# Node.js: re-run cucumberjs tests automatically on each source file change

Tags: cucumberjs

What is the simplest way to tell cucumberjs to watch for source project files changes so that it can re-runs its tests?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a gulp task. Here is more information on how gulp works https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts